# Verbatim environment with catchfilebetweentags package

Tags: verbatim

I would like to use a `verbatim` environment inside an `ExecuteMetaData` call from the `catchfilebetweentags` package.

The use case is that my econometric software creates a fixed-width table that I don't want to convert to a proper table, yet. I can wrap this fixed-width table in tags and send it to a log file. I would like to also wrap the table in `verbatim` so that the table is more legible, but when I add the verbatim environment I get a `Runaway argument?` error. I would like to use the `catchfilebetweentags` package so that I can avoid manually trimming the header and footer from each table (or counting line numbers).

Can I somehow combine fixed-width type with the `catchfilebetweentags` package?

Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\begin{document}
\ExecuteMetaData[inner]{table}
\end{document}
```

Where `inner.tex` is as follows.

```
%<*table>
\begin{verbatim}
col1    col2
1   2
3   4
\end{verbatim}
%</table>
```

Comment: You can put `\ttfamily` before the `\ExecuteMetaData` command, which will give the output in fixed width font. But unless the table data ends each line in `'\\'`, it won't do the carriage return

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Thanks. This might be my ultimate solution if `verbatim` won't work inside tags. I can't append `\\` to each line inside my econometrics suite, but that should be easy enough to script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `catchfilebetweentags` package, I adapted my `readarray` package to do the trick, even using the tags that would otherwise be sought by `catchfilebetweentags`.  It is able to handle multiple tables per input file, interspersed with whatever text (I think).

To handle the search for the `%` in the tag, I temporarily make `$` the comment character.  I don't think this screws things up, but it may if `$` appears in your tabular data.  In that case, you may wish to select a different replacement.

EDITED (12/2016) to remove reliance on the defunct internal `readarray` package command `\record<romannumeral record index>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\newcounter{row}\global\newcounter{column}\newcounter{rcrd}
%\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\parindent 0in

\def\switchcodes{%
  \edef\tmp{\matchcode}%
  \edef\matchcode{\altmatchcode}%
  \edef\altmatchcode{\tmp}%
  \if T\printit\def\printit{F}\else\def\printit{T}\fi%
}
\def\printit{F}

\catcode`\%=12 
\catcode`\$=14 
\newcommand\extracttables[1]{\bgroup\ttfamily$
\catcode`\%=12
\def\matchcode{%<*table>}
\def\altmatchcode{%</table>}
\readrecordarray{#1}\MyArray
\catcode`\$=14
\setcounter{rcrd}{0}$
\whiledo{\value{rcrd} < \nrecords}{$
  \stepcounter{rcrd}$
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\MyArray[\arabic{rcrd}]}{\matchcode}}{$
  \switchcodes\rule{10ex}{.2ex}\\$
  }{\if T\printit\MyArray[\arabic{rcrd}]~\\\fi}$
  }$
\catcode`\%=14$
\catcode`\$=3$
\egroup\vspace{-\baselineskip}$
}
\catcode`\%=14 
\catcode`\$=3 %

\begin{document}
%\ExecuteMetaData[inner]{table}

Testing...

\extracttables{inner.tex}

Back to normal text
\end{document}
```

And here is what I used for inner.tex.  Note that it contains more than one table.  When extracting the table, I place rules above and below it to set it off from the rest of the document.

```
this is
my document prior to
%<*table>
col1    col2
1   2
3   4
%</table>
and my 
document after
the table
%<*table>
col3    col4
1   8
3   47
%</table>
and $ then some more
then
some more
```

[image]

p.s  It doesn't actually do verbatim, but just `\ttfamily`.  If doing verbatim is essential, let me know, and I think I might be able to extend the solution.